# Force close on Intent null return

Tags: android

Hola!  This is my first post.  I'm having trouble with the code
snippet below.

Basically, you click an EditText and you're presented with a file
browser.  If you choose a file all is right with the world.  If you
choose the back/return button on your phone without choosing a file a
force close is caused.  I think this is because I'm returning a null
from the intent, but I do not know how to fix nor what I should try/
catch.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
   filename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.selectFile);
   filename.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           intent.setType("text/csv");
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"),1);
       }
   });
```

The result from LogCat.

02-15 10:03:27.224: DEBUG/dalvikvm(133): GC_EXPLICIT freed 74K, 52% free 2860K/5895K, external 2101K/2456K, paused 69ms
02-15 10:03:30.314: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/.DataManagerActivity } from pid 557
02-15 10:03:30.483: DEBUG/dalvikvm(557): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 228K, 52% free 2656K/5511K, external 1465K/1828K, paused 63ms
02-15 10:03:30.633: WARN/AdMobSDK(557): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-15 10:03:30.643: INFO/AdMobSDK(557): Location information is not being used for ad requests. Enable location
02-15 10:03:30.643: INFO/AdMobSDK(557): based ads with AdManager.setAllowUseOfLocation(true) or by setting 
02-15 10:03:30.643: INFO/AdMobSDK(557): meta-data ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS to true in AndroidManifest.xml
02-15 10:03:30.653: INFO/AdMobSDK(557): Making ad request in test mode
02-15 10:03:31.104: INFO/AdMobSDK(557): Ad returned (493 ms):  AdMob Test Android Web Ad
02-15 10:03:31.224: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/.DataManagerActivity: +855ms
02-15 10:03:33.903: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) } from pid 557
02-15 10:03:34.254: DEBUG/dalvikvm(122): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 20K, 44% free 3456K/6151K, external 2546K/2586K, paused 143ms
02-15 10:03:35.124: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Displayed android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity: +1s111ms
02-15 10:03:36.064: DEBUG/dalvikvm(61): GC_CONCURRENT freed 959K, 47% free 4099K/7687K, external 2440K/3047K, paused 7ms+19ms
02-15 10:03:40.623: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(557): No keyboard for id 0
02-15 10:03:40.633: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(557): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-15 10:03:40.864: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(557): Shutting down VM
02-15 10:03:40.864: WARN/dalvikvm(557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.DataManagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2538)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:958)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.DataManagerActivity.onActivityResult(DataManagerActivity.java:93)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3907)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2492)
02-15 10:03:40.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     ... 11 more
02-15 10:03:41.733: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/.DataManagerActivity
02-15 10:03:42.244: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406cdfd8 com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/.DataManagerActivity}
02-15 10:03:44.084: INFO/Process(557): Sending signal. PID: 557 SIG: 9
02-15 10:03:44.104: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Process com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS (pid 557) has died.
02-15 10:03:44.124: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): channel '406c91a0 com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.BroadcastSMS (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-15 10:03:44.124: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): channel '406c91a0 com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.BroadcastSMS (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-15 10:03:44.154: INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{406c91a0 com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.BroadcastSMS paused=false}
02-15 10:03:44.274: INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{406e5f80 com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS.DataManagerActivity paused=false}
02-15 10:03:44.383: INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{406c4d58 android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity paused=false}
02-15 10:03:44.423: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=165, events=0x8
02-15 10:03:44.423: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=176, events=0x8
02-15 10:03:45.084: WARN/InputManagerService(61): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 557 uid 10032

I think I have this fixed.  Thank you for the clues.

Comment: Please show us the full stacktrace of the fc.  Use Logcat: open the DDMS perspective in eclipse, or run `adb logcat` from the command line.

Comment: The code you have listed there would have nothing to do with your error, if your description is accurate. The problem more likely would be in your `onActivityResult()` method. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: When your control comes back to the Activity , you are not handling the return value properly if return value is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to include the 'else' case where !REULT_OK.  Oops.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // do something
        }
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```